# socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10054]

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, binary, hex

I need to send commands from my PHP web app to a third party server using TCP protocol, so I am using socket for this purpose.
After creating socket and connecting, I write packet data using socket_write() and then when I am trying to read response using socket_read() function I got the following error:

> socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10054]: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

I used different ways to convert data into bytes before send it to the remote server (Convert it to hex, convert it to binary and convert it using pack() function). But all of them gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This error simply says that the server has closed the connection. The reason for this is unknown from the error message and can also not be derived from the description of your setup.

Likely your client has sent something which the server did not like, but it is unclear what your server actually expects and what your client has sent. But the same error can also happen if the server crashed due to unexpected input or other reasons.